# What should I do with my comment that replies to a deleted one?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

Someone posted a comment. I've replied to it. The author deleted their comment.

I see three options here:

1. Delete my comment too
2. Cite their comment before they delete it (I think this is the worst option)
3. Leave my comment (then the conversation becomes unclear, so probably return to #1)

Which one should I choose?

Comment: Delete it, it's no longer needed. Comments aren't designed to be permanent.

Comment: Is your comment relevant even without the other comment, say because it corrects a common misunderstanding?

Comment: "*Which one should I choose?*"—Obviously it depends what it says.

Comment: You might summarise the situation in another comment. Just make sure that a person, who has no idea what the whole history is about, might be able to understand the whole situation.

Comment: The best path this could have taken is that the person deleting their own commented had flagged yours as no longer needed and it would have probably gone poof without anyone even needing to look at the flag. Keep it in mind for the next time where you are in the reverse situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To quote [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment):

> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.

and should be treated as such—i.e., assume all comments can (would?) get deleted eventually.

If your comment doesn't have any intrinsic value of its own other than replying to another comment, once that comment was removed, your comment is useless, and should also be removed.

If it has some value of its own, regardless of the original comment it replied to, you can (and should) leave it.